# UI view frame not refreshing in UItableview ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to set a frame to UIview at runtime but the frame is not updating for some reason.

```
    CGRect newFrame = cell.candidatesPollProgress.frame;
    float c = [[dCandidatesPollProgress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]floatValue];

    newFrame.size.width = (c/100)*120;
    newFrame.size.height = 8;
    [cell.candidatesPollProgress setFrame:newFrame];
    cell.candidatesPollProgress.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

I debugged it and the frame contains the actual values but they are not being updated.Any ideas?

Comment: probably you use wrong "cell"?

Comment: Did you use autolayout? If so, try to change constraints

Comment: Is color applied for your cell

Comment: @R.K. thanks that was the problem..

Answer (score 2):

If you are used `AutoLayout` it's did't work. you have update constraints like below

Change the constraints value using take custom cell & provide `IBOutlet` to view 
Custom cell class header file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *viewHeight_constraint;
```

In cell for row or any action do like below

```
cell.viewHeight_constraint.constant = 40.0; //value

 [cell.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

 [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
```